# How to texture - Repeating patterns of cylindrical meshes

Tags: texturing, uv

Basically, I have made a spaceship model that I tested in a game and the time has come to texture it.

The original ships in that game use universal textures, so every mesh has its UVs set to a piece of each chosen texture. Mine is going to be the same in that regard (i.e. no custom UV-unwraps with painted textures).

So, the problem is this - when we have a cylindrical engine mesh, we want a repeating pattern on the adjacent faces, like this: https://p3d.in/sWsav

How do I unwrap my engines and "mirror" each side of that cylinder to use the same UV-coordinates on the texture map? Because, as you can see, its a repeating pattern.

This is the texture:
[image: the repeating texture]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just have to make an unwrap reset in this case ?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this - https://s18.postimg.io/nf63smeop/Untitled.jpg  Those are turret slots, each UV that makes up the 10 faces, is pie-shaped (like pieces of a cake). Doing a Reset will make all UVs into n-gons or squares!

Comment: So, unwrap your face and adapt your texture. http://i.imgur.com/SlyHPJC.png I don't exactly understand where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Asked a person about this and got the answer - you just unwrap the textures (on the cylinder) the normal way, then detach each faces in the UV map, rotate and move them on top of eachother, then box select, grab and put them wherever I want.

Mosaic effect - achieved.

Thanks for the answers, tho!